# Changing owner of NAS drive

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, freebsd, mount, samba

I have setup a Freenas system that I would like to mount on my Ubuntu Desktop. Freenas is configured with **cifs** service.

When I open the freenas server in nautilus smb://freenas/homenas/ I can create and delete files without a problem.

Mounting the server also works:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.108/homenas /media/bigHD username=test,password=123
```

The **owner of all the files in /media/bigHD is tom** (my non root account).

However **when I create a file under /media/bigHD its is owned by root**. I really do not wish to chown every file/folder after I create it.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the problem I had to specify the gid and uid. Would have saved so much time if I just read the man page more carefully...

> ```
> uid=arg
>            sets the uid that will own all files or directories on the
> ```
>
> mounted
>                  filesystem when the server does not provide ownership
>   information.
>                  It may be specified as either a username or a numeric uid.
>   When not
>                  specified, the default is uid 0. The mount.cifs helper must
>   be at
>                  version 1.10 or higher to support specifying the uid in
>   non-numeric
>                  form. See the section on FILE AND DIRECTORY OWNERSHIP AND
>                  PERMISSIONS below for more information.
>
> ```
> gid=arg
>        sets the gid that will own all files or directories on the
> ```
>
> mounted
>              filesystem when the server does not provide ownership
>   information.
>              It may be specified as either a groupname or a numeric gid.
>   When
>              not specified, the default is gid 0. The mount.cifs helper must
>   be
>              at version 1.10 or higher to support specifying the gid in
>              non-numeric form. See the section on FILE AND DIRECTORY
>   OWNERSHIP
>              AND PERMISSIONS below for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Using Ubuntu 12.4

I also had the problem, now even though `mount.cifs -V` returns version 5.1.

I still can only get my NAS to mount with specified UID and GID if they are given as numeric form. Otherwise I'd just get the mounts as root permission, due to the sticky on `mount.cifs`.

Interestingly, if provided in the non-numeric form. The UID and GID were still picked up correctly.

Anyway, I put this here if anyone has the same problem, working fstab line was:

```
//mynas/scratch /media/scratch cifs noauto,users,_netdev,credentials=/home/meeee/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1002,file_mode=0774,dir_mode=0775 0 0
```

Comment: Interesting that version 5.1 doesn't support non-numeric uid form as the man page says "version 1.10 or higher" would support this feature. I guess my man page is out of date or the version being reported is like 0.5.1 or something.